# SSH login asks for password

Tags: ssh, vps, login

I've followed the [steps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-your-first-digitalocean-droplet-virtual-server) of Digital Ocean to create a droplet. I'm using Cloud9IDE for the development of my app.

The steps suggested using SSH for login. So I followed the steps:

1. `ssh-keygen -t rsa` to create the public and private key.
2. `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_digital_ocean.pub` (this is the name I gave the ssh file) to display to public key
3. Added the public key to the droplet. As part of the creation process of the droplet on Digital Ocean, you can enter the public key, which I did.

Now I try to log in using `ssh -i id_rsa_digital_ocean root@IP_ADDRESS` where I use the IP address of the created droplet. But then it asks for a password and when I just hit enter it says 'Permission denied'. The problem is I don't even received a password because since I created a SSH key, I'm supposed to log in that way.

Comment: Have you tried to use full path: `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_digital_ocean root@IP_ADDRESS`. If it won't help, you need to provide debug output of connection to investigate the issue. We ran out of magic 8 balls.

Comment: Added answer. Happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use full path: `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_digital_ocean root@IP_ADDRESS`.